# Объединение аккаунтов stackoverflow

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow

Суть - у меня есть аккаунт здесь, на ***ru.stackoverflow***, и на обычном ***stackoverflow***. Аккаунты-то разные, есть ли возможность объединить их, чтобы пользоваться одним?

И почему, зайдя на главную страницу ***ru.stackoverflow***, я не вижу самых свежих вопросов, в т.ч. которые задал я только что?

Comment: Задал этот вопрос Николаю (см. комментарий): http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/3774//аккаунты-раздвоение-аккаунтов#3780 Но похоже, что Ru.SO позиционируется как еще одно сообщество, не связанное с самим SO (разве что общим доменом), а в платформе StackExchange на каждое сообщество у пользователя отдельный аккаунт, и в каждом из аккаунтов можно видеть остальные аккаунты (графа Accounts/Учетные записи).

Comment: Вы можете связать аккаунты, но репутация будет раздельной, как и на любых двух других сайтах сети Stack Exchange. Подробнее: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/119/181472

Comment: @timofeybondarev что-то я одну метку удалил, а другую пропустил.